# <option value="value1,value2"> in Thymleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to do something like

```
<option value="value1,value2">
```

in thymleaf. I know for one value all i have to do is

```
<option th:value="${value1}">
```

How to pass two values in select option in Thyemleaf.

Comment: <option th:value="${value1} +' '+ ${value2}"> is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the templating correctly:

```
<option th:value="${value1} +' '+ ${value2}">
```